# Update quickbooks invoice with php

Tags: php, cakephp, curl, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

We need to update a single invoice in quickbooks online using PHP (CakePHP 1.3). I've looked around and the only thing I've been able to find is the "keith palmer php api" which seems a bit over kill for the simple nature of what we are trying to accomplish.

Has anyone accomplished this? I don't imagine it would take more than a simple curl execution to quickbooks to update an invoice? Please advise.

Comment: So have you tried a simple cURL implementation?  What specific problem are you having?

Comment: I've not tried a curl implementation, I'm curious if one exists, something more simplistic.

Comment: You're not going to find a "simple" implementation, because it's not a terribly simple API. It's not as simple as just CURL because requests are OAuth signed, and you need to go through a 3-legged OAuth process to get the access tokens, etc.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly. You must log in to the API on the index page in order to start talking with Quick Books? I'm simply wanting to update an invoice in Quick Books Online.

Comment: Is there no means of silently posting an update to an invoice?

Comment: You have to authenticate to QuickBooks Online *ONCE*. This is obviously required because otherwise anyone could do anything with anyone's QuickBooks data. Once you've authenticated, you can then send any data you want to QuickBooks Online, silently, without user interaction, forever going forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Has anyone accomplished this?

Yes! Many people!

> I don't imagine it would take more than a simple curl execution to quickbooks to update an invoice?

Unfortunately, it does require a bit more than this.

It requires a bit more than this for 3 main reasons:

1. Intuit requires you to authenticate to QuickBooks Online (just once) via [OAuth](http://oauth.net/). Curl doesn't have built-in OAuth support, so you'll need to use some sort of library or code to sign your OAuth requests. OAuth is *not* a trivial protocol/signing mechanism.
2. To update objects in QuickBooks Online, you have to send Intuit the latest `SyncToken` value. The latest `SyncToken` value can only be fetched by first *querying* for the invoice in QuickBooks via the API. i.e. to make an update, you *also* have to first be able to query.
3. Intuit requires you to register an "app" to connect to QuickBooks Online. This provides setup steps and requires info for the OAuth flow.

With that said, using this library:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

Really isn't very difficult.

Just follow the quick-start guide:

- http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Intuit_Partner_Platform_Quick-Start

And check out the example of doing an invoice update:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/example_invoice_update.php

It looks something like this:

```
    $InvoiceService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Invoice();

    // Get the existing invoice first (you need the latest SyncToken value)
    $invoices = $InvoiceService->query($Context, $realm, "SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE Id = '34' ");
    $Invoice = $invoices[0];

    print_r($Invoice);

    $Invoice->setTxnDate(date('Y-m-d'));  // Update the invoice date to today's date 

    if ($resp = $InvoiceService->update($Context, $realm, $Invoice->getId(), $Invoice))
    {
        print('&nbsp; Updated!<br>');
    }
```

Comment: Once again I want to thank you, I did not understand the OAuth process and how it worked. Once I sat down and read through everything I have a clear and better understanding of everything. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the following steps to communicate with QBO V3 REST APIs using IPP's official PHP sdk.

To start development using QB API, you need to create an IA apps in Intuit's appcenter.

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0010_signup

From the above link you will get - apptoken, consumer key and consumer Secret. You can use the above 3 keys in IPPOAuthPlayground(PFB link) to get the access token and access secret corresponding to your QB Online account.

- https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth

Using the above tokens, you can call any REST endpoints against your QB Online account.

PHP devkit is available here.

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits

PHP devkit user guide

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0210_ipp_php_sdk_for_quickbooks_v3/0002_synchronous_calls/0001_data_service_apis

Answer (score 0):

Completed! With CakePHP 1.3 we placed Keith Palmers API in the webroot directory. Once authorized we then added the below function in our payments controller.

```
    function updateQBInvoice($invoiceNumber = null, $depositAmount = null) {            
        include(APP."webroot".DS."quickbooks-php".DS."docs".DS."example_app_ipp_v3".DS."config.php");
        $IPP = new QuickBooks_IPP($dsn);
        $creds = $IntuitAnywhere->load($the_username, $the_tenant);
        $IPP->authMode(QuickBooks_IPP::AUTHMODE_OAUTH, $the_username, $creds);  
        $realm = $creds['qb_realm'];

        if ($Context = $IPP->context()) {
            $IPP->version(QuickBooks_IPP_IDS::VERSION_3);
            $InvoiceService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Invoice();
            $invoices = $InvoiceService->query($Context, $realm, "SELECT * FROM Invoice");

            foreach ($invoices as $Invoice) {
                $docNumber = $Invoice->getDocNumber();
                if ($docNumber == $invoiceNumber) {

                    /* Set the invoice as paid. */
                    $Invoice->setDeposit($depositAmount);

                    if ($resp = $InvoiceService->update($Context, $realm, $Invoice->getId(), $Invoice)) {
                        echo '&nbsp; Updated!<br>';
                    } else {
                        echo '&nbsp; ' . $InvoiceService->lastError() . '<br>';
                    }
                }
            }               
        } else {
            echo 'Unable to load a context...?';
        }
    }
```

I imagine there is a better way of grabbing the invoice but I have yet to discover it. I tried adjusting the query to "SELECT * FROM Invoices WHERE DocNumber=XXX" however that did not work.

I would like to thank everyone for their assistance, Thank you!

Comment: SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE DocNumber = 'your doc number'

Comment: The above query does not work. It returns a null object/result. Only way I've found that works is to retrieve all invoices and loops through to find the one I want. Is this a bug?

Comment: It works just fine for me - we literally do a few thousand queries a day like that. Post the output of $InvoiceService->lastRequest() and $InvoiceService->lastResponse() and maybe someone can help.

Comment: @KeithPalmer-consolibyte I've post the response and request.

Answer (score 0):

@Keith

Request:

```
   [GET https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/210896252/query?query=SELECT+%2A+FROM+Invoice+WHERE+DocNumber%3D2060 HTTP/1.1
    Content-Type: text/plain
    Authorization: OAuth realm="", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_signature="xxx",  oauth_nonce="gZxqN", oauth_timestamp="1400779429", oauth_token="xxx", oauth_consumer_key="xxx", oauth_version="1.0"

    ]
```

Response:

```
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 22 May 2014 17:23:49 GMT
intuit_tid: 6f7b9023-3c8e-401c-9028-711300475720
Content-Length: 327
Via: 1.1 ipp-gateway-.net
Content-Type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
QBO-Version: 73.223
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private
Expires: 0

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2014-05-22T10:23:50.031-07:00"><Fault type="ValidationFault"><Error code="4000"><Message>Error parsing query</Message><Detail>QueryParserError: Encountered &quot; &lt;INTEGER&gt; &quot;2060 &quot;&quot; at line 1, column 39.
Was expecting one of:
    &quot;false&quot; ...
    &quot;true&quot; ...
    </Detail></Error></Fault></IntuitResponse>]
```

Comment: View > Source in your browser. You're not posting the entire response or request. Also, you need to add this as a COMMENT to my answer, not as a whole separate answer. Or if it's easier for you to use forums, go to http://www.consolibyte.com/forum/

Comment: @KeithPalmer-consolibyte I've updated the post with the proper info.

Comment: Look at the query I posted again. Notice that there are 'single quotes' around 'your doc number'.

Comment: CORRECT: SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE DocNumber = '1234'

Comment: INCORRECT: SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE DocNumber = 1234